# javascript regex for string starting with forward slash followed by alphanum chars and no space

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a JavaScript regular expression for validating a string that should start with a forward slash ("/") followed by alphanumeric characters with no spaces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
/^\/[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

i.e.:

- `^` - anchor the start of the string
- `\/` - a literal forward slash, escaped
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more letters or digits.  You can also use `\d` instead of `0-9`
- `$` - up to the end of the string
- `/i` - case independent

Answer (score 3):

This should do it. This takes a-z and A-Z and 0-9.

```
/^\/[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

[image: regexper]

Image from [Regexper.com](https://regexper.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
/^\/[\da-z]+$/i.test('/123')    // true
/^\/[\da-z]+$/i.test('/blah')   // true
/^\/[\da-z]+$/i.test('/bl ah')  // false
/^\/[\da-z]+$/i.test('/')       // false
```